# Pyomo DAE optimal control problem with FREE end points

Tags: python, optimization, differential-equations, pyomo

I use pyomo.dae to solve differential equation optimization
I defined a set

```
m.e = ContinuousSet(bounds=(e0, ef))
```

But I want `ef` to be free as variable. It's a flexible end points differential problem. How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change your differential equation

```
y'(x) = f(x,y(x))
```

over a flexible interval `[e0, ef]` 
to a version over the standard interval `[0,1]` via

```
u'(s) = T*f(e0+T*s, u(s))
```

where now `e0` and `T=ef-e0` can be treated like any other parameter.

Comment: `ef` is a flexible point during the optimization, it means `T` is not a constant value. I think I should call it FREE end point.

Comment: Yes. This way the integrator has a fixed end point and the optimizator can change the true end-point by manipulating `T`.

Comment: You can find this "trick" also in the second part of this example: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jckantor/ND-Pyomo-Cookbook/blob/master/notebooks/06.03-Path-Planning-for-a-Simple-Car.ipynb